# Bypass UAC completely

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2013, permissions, windows-8.1, uac

In my school, we have low-level user accounts (obviously) so we can do everything we want, except changing important stuff etc.

However, the PC which was assigned to me has been having some issues, namely Visual Studio not functioning anymore (it literally crashes 2 sec after hitting the shortcut).
After doing some research I found that an repair + update are needed to fix it.

So I told my teacher (so he could tell the network admin) & he assigned me a different PC, which ALSO has issues.
This new (2nd) PC, Visual Studio works, to an extent...

I can do just about anything in there, except for what may just be Visual Studio's most important & useful function, which is debugging.
Everytime I try to debug my code it gives me an error:

`Unable to start project: Invalid pointer.`

All I can do right now, is launch my projects without the debugger & hope that it works, because if it doesn't, I won't get any information as to why it won't work.

Again after doing some research, a simple repair/update should do the trick.

Here's where my real problem lies; as I don't have permissions to make any changes to the PC (not permitted by UAC) and my teacher doesn't have the necessary rights on his account either, I'm stuck with 2 PC's with a VS install that's broken.

So my question:

How can I run the Visual Studio installer without having UAC request a password from me?

OR

If you happen to know how to fix it without using UAC, please share.

Note: I tried Task Scheduler, however UAC (again) won't allow me to create new tasks. I tried making one with elevated permissions & it simply didn't work...

Comment: I've voted to close as off-topic, "may be able to get help on Super User" but I'm not sure that asking for help breaking into someone else's system is on-topic there either.  The network admin should be fixing the problem.  Note that in my experience most schools would suspend or expel you for doing that, no matter what your reason for doing so.

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't sure where to post it so I simply posted it on the one I use the most. Anyway, my teacher has told the net admin about 2 months ago, yet he still hasn't bothered to fix it... Also, when I tried bypassing through task scheduler, I told my teacher about it beforehand & he simply said I should try it, because he knows why I want to do it & he's getting quite sick of it as well. Either way, I'll close this & post it on Super User instead :) thx